# Sticky Navigation - Formatting Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I'm currently creating a wordpress theme that has a sticky menu. I've got the basic workings of it. The only problem I'm having is when it snaps to a different position, it isn't quite snapping to the top of the section. 
Instead of the bottom of the menu snapping to the top of the section, the top of the navigation is appearing with what seems to be a 20px gap above it. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue? I've attached the CSS below.

```
#headerwrapper {
width:1500px;
margin: 0 auto !important;  
height:138px;
position:fixed;
background:#212c2e;

}
```

The website is www.featurebooth.com.au/wordpress

Another issue I'm having is the navigation appears to disappear behind the gallery plugin that I've used. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the incorrect formatting

[image: Incorrect Formatting]

This is the correct formatting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
#headerwrapper {
  top: 0; (or whatever fixes it)
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

The top will put it at the top of the page and the z-index will make sure it sits above all other elements.

Comment: The z-index worked perfectly for making the navigation appear above the gallery. 

I'm still having the issue with it snapping to the wrong area though. Is it possible to somehow make the bottom of the navigation snap to the top of the section? Rather than the top of the navigation? The height of 138px is hiding part of the section.

The only thing I can really think of doing is creating an empty div class with a height of 138px. Which unfortunately makes the design look a bit funny.